# extracting a number from a stream using sed/grep/awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

i am writting a script and i need to get a number out of the shell command output. The command & its return is

```
$ git branch -a -v --no-abbrev --contains $(git rev-parse HEAD)
* (HEAD detached at c5246b6)     c5246b6907e46795741853852462914e7a5f60de Merge pull request 1166 from testPR into dev
  remotes/origin-pull/1166/merge c5246b6907e46795741853852462914e7a5f60de Merge pull request 1166 from testPR into dev
```

i am trying to extract the `1166` out of the result by using sed over the piped result. Something like

```
$ git branch -a -v --no-abbrev --contains $(git rev-parse HEAD) | sed <pattern>
```

to get the 1166 
My patterns so far doesn't seem to get the number i am expecting.

Comment: Those that link belong here?

Comment: I think it's a hint to accept more answers, seeing that out of 60 questions, you only accepted 12 answers? Just a guess, though. Assuming that you get answers that actually solve your problem, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems that you're trying to extract the part of your remote branch name between last 2 slashes. And you may use `grep` with perl interpreted pattern to achieve that, here you are,

```
$ git branch ... | grep -oP '[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]+$)'
1166
```

Brief explanation,

- -o: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts
- `[^\/]+` : `grep` command would print this part, non-slash pattern
- `(?=\/[^\/]+$)` : matches words ahead of the las slash of the line `[^\/]+$`

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to my exact question, but i am able to get what i want by modifying my bash command.

```
git branch -r -v --no-abbrev --contains $(git rev-parse HEAD) | awk '{print $1}'
```

This returns: `origin-pull/1166/merge` , which is what i want

notice the -r in the command, -a will return both local and remote git branch info. This way, i can cheat on the sed pattern again.